# ACM document format vertical space

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, acm

It is my first time writing a document using the ACM class (sig-alternate). However, I am encountering a big vertical space on the first column of my first page, that shifted 5-6 lines of my Introduction to the second colum (see picture below). I have tried to use the command `\raggedbottom` but it doesn't change anything. I suppose this is due to the ACM `\acmcopyright` command, which, if setted correctly, add a small copyright text which almost fill the gap you can see on the figure. 
Finally, I don't understand how to get rid of the ISBN and DOI for now. On the proceedings I have read which used the same class, no DOI or ISBN appeared. Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: vertical space]

Comment: Solved it using the command \def\@copyrightspace{\relax}

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, use the command `\def\@copyrightspace{\relax}` which is not defined in the ACM sig-alternate guide but in the tex sample.